# DLL Not Found Exception in exported unmanaged C++ DLL

Tags: visual-c++

I have a unmanaged C++ DLL this is imported in another C# project.I am getting "DLL Not Found exception for this DLL while trying to access first method in it.I checked in dependency walker it complains about "msvcr90d" .I hav eC++ project created in VS 2008 using .Net Framework 2.0 and C# project created in VS 2010 using framework 3.5.

Is there any way using which I can find out the missing link?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

msvcr90d.dll is a debug version of msvcr90.dll... are you experiencing this problem on your development machine or on another machine (which does not have VS installed)? If you're experiencing the problem only on machines that don't have Visual Studio installed, you should do a release build instead of a debug build.

Comment: I am experiencing it on development machine.

Answer (score 0):

The complaint from Dependancy Walker is most likely misleading. The problem may have something to do with manifests, but it might also not. You may try several options (possibly combined), and see what happens:

1. use release DLL in debug C#
2. remove manifest from DLL, or put one, if manifest is actually missing
3. place all needing DLL files where C# .exe resides
4. check and double-check that there are no differences between debug and release DLL's, apart from different underlying DLL's.